# write/edit/overwrite a json file in react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I know how to read the json file just by importing it

`import file from './config/data.json';
 console.log(file);`
.

But is there an easy way to write or edit on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you absolutely want to read/write files you could use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs).

If you want to persist application specific settings I would recommend using [AsyncStorage](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

Answer (score 9):

Use AsyncStorage for saving local settings:

**The following is to set your settings in your code (This example is for some Switch**

```
async setSettings() {
  try {
    var obj = {};
    var settings = await AsyncStorage.getItem('settings');
    settings = JSON.parse(result);
    Object.assign(obj, settings);
    this.setState(obj);
  }
  catch(e) { }
  finally { }
}
```

**The following is to change your settings in your code**

```
switchChanged(field, value) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[field] = value;
  AsyncStorage.getItem('settings').then(function(strResult) {
    var result = JSON.parse(strResult) || {};
    Object.assign(result, obj);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(result));
  });
  this.setState(obj);
}
```

**And finally the call at the render method**

```
<Switch
  onValueChange={(value) => this.switchChanged('reminders', value)}
  value={this.state.reminders} />
```

*Hope it can help you :)*