# Update existing field in local json file in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm working on an app where I have some data stored in the local JSON file. Initially, I'm showing that data using SectionList. And there are some fields to update the values of some fields of that data.
My data looks like this:

```
   { 
        "title": "Terminal Settings",
        "data": [
            { "title": "Keypad", "id": 1, "isSelected": false},
            { "title": "Menu", "id": 2 , "isSelected": false},
            { "title": "Tabs", "id": 3, "isSelected": false},
            { "title": "Mobile", "id": 4, "isSelected": false}
        ]
    },
```

Now from UI, I want to change the status of `isSelected` field through the checkbox and also want to change it in the JSON file. So whenever I will access this data it should show `isSelected: true`.

How to do this? Do I need to use `AsyncStorage` for this?

Comment: are you using redux or not ?

Comment: are you using json more than one place ?

Comment: Yes, no I’m not using redux! For this taks they have gave me option of AsyncStorage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [write/edit/overwrite a json file in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672144/write-edit-overwrite-a-json-file-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will definely have to open and modify the content of your file at some point, so your should need some filesystem. The best would be to simple get your json object with

```js
const myData = require('./myDataJsonFile.json');
```

then modify it with for example $json[0]['data'][1]['isSelected'] = true

and finally save this in your file, replacing the file content with your $json

Comment: Hi coderpolo, Thank you for answer. But this answer doesn’t solve my problem. I’m able to read data and show on UI. I want to modify it.

Comment: Okay, i guess you managed to 'clone' the json data in your file in an object that your UI can modify, then you will need to add an extra step where you save your object in the desired file. I think for that you should check something like this : https://www.waldo.com/blog/react-native-fs

Comment: const writeFile = () => {
   var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';
   RNFS.writeFile(path, 'This is a content from Waldo', 'utf8')
    .then(() => console.log('FILE WRITTEN!'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
}